# Three.js - async update of Mesh objects poisitions

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am developing an Three.js app, where I draw a grid which displays objects. I have multiple objects which are rendered on the grid according to their positions. I create and render the elements according to data which is fetch from a REST API- which I poll every 300ms. Currently I am doing the fetch calls inside the animate() function, where I check to see if 300ms have passed from last request. When I receive the data from the API I iterate on all mesh object and update their position to their new positions.

I am having trouble making the object move smoothly from position to position - the elements just sort of "jump" on the grid when the new position is set. 
How can I make the objects move smoothly? Is there a better way of updating objects position and handling the async data from the API?

I didn't add my code because its very long and most of it is not relevant..

EDIT: - some more info

In my animate function I fetch data to get new objects to add to scene or if item already exists, update their positions. See this code example to better understand what i'm trying to do:

```
  const objects = {}; // This holds all objects Meshes in scene

    function animate(){
      if (new Date().getTime() - lastTime  > 300){
         axios
          .get(DATA_URL)
          .then(data => {
            /** Data is array of objects to add or update in scene.
             *  Here I am iterating over the data array and see if item exists  
             *  in objects or not. If exists - I just update Mesh positions, 
             . otherwise I create a new mesh and add it to the scene
*/


             data.forEach(item => {
               let mesh;
               if (objects[item.id]){
                 mesh = objects[item.id]
               }else{

                 mesh = // Create new mesh
                 objects[item.id] = mesh
               }

              // update position
               mesh.position.set(item.x, item.y, item.z);
             })
          })
      }
    }
```

Comment: Any example of the code you use to move the objects?

Comment: @prisoner849 I added simple code snippet to better explain my self. In my case I receive an array of objects to update.. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If I got you correctly, then, as an option, you can do it with the Tween.js library:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(1, 2, 3);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

var items = [];
setInterval( addItem, 300);

function addItem(){
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({val:0}).to({val:1}, 100).onUpdate(
    function(value){
      items.forEach(v => {
        v.position.z -= value.val * 0.5;
      })
    }
  ).onComplete(item)
  .start();
}

function item(){
  var item = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.25, 4, 2), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: Math.random() * 0xffffff, wireframe: true}));
  scene.add(item);
  items.push(item);
}

render();
function render(){
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  TWEEN.update();
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body{
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/91/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tween.js/17.2.0/Tween.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Tween.. I'll be sure to check if it fits my needs. Thanks